# How to make a abstract class with default comments on it?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, abstract

I have a superclass with an abstract method I want to provide some comments on the method and if any subclasses inherited this method this comments will come along with it.

```
class MySuper {

    //some comments
    protected abstract void myAbstractMethod();
}

class MyChild extends MySuper {

    //some comments
    @Override
    public void updateLanguage() {

    }
}
```

Comment: add proper java-docs, no comments

Comment: Is great if we have this type of feature in the future?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add proper java-doc comments, than that implementing class will get those.

This technique is used in various places inside the jdk too - methods are inherited only to get their documentation.

Answer (score 0):

When defining an abstract method you should use java-doc to help someone who will have to write the implementation.

On the extending class, I would expect to find a java-doc explaining this very implementation.